# Targeting aspects based annotation on a class with Spring and AspectJ

Tags: java, spring, annotations, aspectj, aop

How to make an aspect that targets all public methods that belong to a class that is marked with specific annotation? In following *method1()* and *method2()* should be processed by the aspect and *method3()* should not be processed by the aspect.

```
@SomeAnnotation(SomeParam.class)
public class FooServiceImpl extends FooService {
    public void method1() { ... }
    public void method2() { ... }
}

public class BarServiceImpl extends BarService {
    public void method3() { ... }
}
```

If I put annotations on method level, this aspect will work and match the method calls.

```
@Around("@annotation(someAnnotation)")
public Object invokeService(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, SomeAnnotation someAnnotation) 
 throws Throwable { 
   // need to have access to someAnnotation's parameters.
   someAnnotation.value();
```

}

I am using Spring and proxy based aspects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following should work

```
@Pointcut("@target(someAnnotation)")
public void targetsSomeAnnotation(@SuppressWarnings("unused") SomeAnnotation someAnnotation) {/**/}

@Around("targetsSomeAnnotation(someAnnotation) && execution(* *(..))")
public Object aroundSomeAnnotationMethods(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, SomeAnnotation someAnnotation) throws Throwable {
    ... your implementation..
}
```

Comment: Does not work in Spring Boot 2+

Answer (score 2):

This works in Spring Boot 2:

```
@Around("@within(xyz)")
public Object method(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, SomeAnnotation xyz) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println(xyz.value());
    return joinPoint.proceed();
}
```

Note that based on the method argument type (`SomeAnnotation xyz`), Spring and AspectJ  will know which annotation you are looking for, so the `xyz` does not have to be the name of your annotation.

Comment: This works great. but i am confused. I am seeing behavior where @ target is used to annotate class level, and @ annotation on method level - this is when aspects work. Any idea why this is happening? I am confused? Why i can't use @ annotation on class level so all methods are affected?

Answer (score 0):

Using @target and reading the type level annotation with reflection works.

```
@Around("@target(com.example.SomeAnnotation)")
public Object invokeService(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
```